# tRPC mutateAsync returns nothing

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-query, trpc.io

This is my first attempt to use tRPC. I created a mutation named "add", which receive a URL as parameter and returns a hardcoded slug

Router

```
export const entryRouter = router({
  add: publicProcedure
    .input(input)
    .output(output)
    .mutation(async ({ ctx, input }) => {
      const slug = "test"

      return { slug }
    }),
})
```

Usage

```
const addEntry = trpc.entry.add.useMutation()

...

const { slug } = await addEntry.mutateAsync({ url: 'https://example.com' })

console.log(JSON.stringify({ slug })
```

However, it only prints an empty object (`{}`)

What am I doing wrong?

Full source-code https://github.com/skhaz/url-shortener

PS. I am using with NextJS, on the inspector, on the network, I can see the slug value on the response JSON

Comment: how does `addEntry` looks?

Comment: @FerToasted `const addEntry = trpc.entry.add.useMutation()`

Comment: maybe if you try to return a promise instead for the slug? `const slug => await Promise(res => res('test');`

Comment: @FerToasted in the HTTP response I can see the value correct, the problem is on mutateAsync I guess

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that I was using `superjson` as the transformer. Removing it solved the issue

Comment: Did you figure out exactly what superjson was messing up? I've been using trpc with superjson on pretty big apps and I've never had any issue with it, i'm curious.

Comment: I have no idea. The only diff is when using superjson, the payload gets wrapped into a json field (the name of the field is json)

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me also in T3Stack(https://github.com/t3-oss/create-t3-turbo) after upgrading superjson, @trpc/client and @trpc/server and packages:

```
"@trpc/client": "^10.9.0 -> ^ 10.13.2"
"@trpc/server": "^10.9.0 -> ^10.13.2",
"superjson": "1.9.1 -> ^1.12.1",
```

But it did not mess only with mutateAsync but with whole trpc types as every function that trpc route object provides was inferred as any.

After bumping it back to lower version all started working as expected.

Comment: I opened the issue here so you can follow up if they come up with a better solution than downgrading versions or removing superjson.
https://github.com/t3-oss/create-t3-turbo/issues/191